# Phonegap's window.open doesn't work in Apple review

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I've built an app that opens a website using window.open as soon as it loads. When I run it using Phonegap it works fine. When I build it in xcode and run it on the simulator using Macincloud it can't connect (I assume this is due to connection limitations within that development environment; in addition the Macincloud browser can connect to the site with no issues). I submitted the app for review and according to the response it doesn't get a response from the website. What is necessary to get this to work correctly?

Edit: after getting the app on my phone with TestFlight it does work but takes nearly 1m to bring up the resulting website. That may have been the cause of the error reported.

The code that opens the window is:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    if (navigator && navigator.connection && navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        navigator.notification.alert('An internet connection is required to continue');
    } else {
      var onInApp = window.open('https://website.com/', '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=no,closebuttoncaption=Done,toolbar=no');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You said yourself there may be connection limitations in that environment.  Can you open a browser on MacInCloud and connect to the site you're trying to connect to?  If so, then there's something wrong specific to the app and not your environment.  Test that out and then contact MacInCloud if it doesn't connect from a browser.

Comment: The site does load just fine in a browser. However it also loads from the app when running within Phonegap. Other discussions suggest that the xcode simulator may have restricted network access.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your URL has any SSL exceptions. IOS apps by default don't load urls with ssl errors. (example: while accessing URL in browser, if it says "Your connection is not private". Such URL will not load in iOS app).

Also kindly check whether you followed iOS ATS security guidelines. Check below link for more information. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html